# Suitable structure that makes the statement False

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

∀x∀y∀z((P(x,y) Λ P(y,z)) → P(x,z))

I know that the only way the statement is False, is if P(x,y)=True, P(y,z)=True, and P(x,z)=False, however, I'm unable to identify any suitable structure (values) that would make the statement False. Is it even possible?

Comment: I love my wife, my wife loves her mother, but ....

Comment: I can't believe I was just thinking about numerical values. Thank you so much!

Comment: Any not transitive relation.